# What does href="{% url 'profile' %} mean?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**Update 2**

I think my confusion came because I did not account for the fact that my project `django_project3` is the default project.

**Update**

I looked at [Using {% url ??? %} in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599423/using-url-in-django-templates) but it didn't fully answer my question.

**Original Post**

I tried to Google my question but ended up with 1000s of pages of Python theory and no straight answer.

I have a project called `Blog` and in it there is a file called `base.html`. And it contains the line of code  `<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Home</a>`.

But in `Blogs urls.py` file there is no URL pattern called profile.

Whereas in my project `django_project3`, in the `urls.py` file there is a URL pattern called profile.

Does the percentage sign get the code to look in every `urls.py` file?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using {% url ??? %} in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599423/using-url-in-django-templates)

Comment: I can see that post covers a similar issue to my own. But no that post doesn't fully answer my question.

Comment: This is a template tag for rendering URLs. How it works is described fairly thoroughly [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url` is a [built-in template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to avoid hard-coding.

`{% %}` is template render syntax